# Change cell image with it's indexPath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Currently I'm using:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

to change the image of the cell.

But how can I change it if I only know the indexPath.row?

I have tried:

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0].imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
  UITableVieCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
  cell.imageView.image = ...
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath returns a cell, but you aren't allocating that cell to any variable.  So it just goes away.  You need to store the returned pointer into a variable then modify the imageView using that value, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question? `How can i change it if i only know the indexpath.row?` This question doesnt make sense. All you need to change a certain cell is the `indexPath`.

```
UITableVieCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

This code is just a bit different from @JMD. His will only change the image for the very first cell. If you want every cell, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will get called for each newly created cell. Therefore, inserting `indexPath.row` instead of `0` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks you :-) BTW it isn't indexPath.row, it's just indexPath :-)

Comment: @CodeBandits: just indexPath, not indexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too,

```
((UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0]).imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Comment: Why does everybody here think an indexpath was an integer? Why the cast? the compiler knows that cellforRowAtIndexPath: returns a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** so that it can determine which image to show, and call

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]
```

rather than calling **cellForRowAtIndexPath** directly. You should **never** call this method directly, as changes will not be permanent if you are using queued up cells. Make your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method smart enough to determine what to show, and reload the row at the indexPath.